# How Do I Print A Burn Down Chart From Jira?

Tags: jira, burndowncharts

I want to print my burn down charts from the 'Reports' Tab in Jira. There is no specific 'print' functionality. When I try to just print from within the browser, it will print the whole window, not just the chart.

According to the [Atlassian Community forum](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Questions/Print-Burndown-Chart/qaq-p/44211), there is no solution to this yet. Has anyone come up with something?

Comment: In the meantime, until fixed in Jira, I created a simple online tool to print burn down charts: [printyourburndown.com](https://printyourburndown.com)

Comment: You could also look at browser extensions allowing to capture screenshots (and print them) with more control. I'm thinking about Nimbus Screenshot in Firefox but I'm sure there are plenty more.

Answer (score -1):

Mouse right click on the white spaces underneath the tile " BurndownChart", it gives you the option to print. This is how I have been able to print the BD chart.

Comment: I read this elsewhere before, but it does not work here (Jira 7.12.1 on premise). I can of course print the whole page including the data table below the chart, but this is not what I want.